# Python calculator error when dividing numbers

Tags: python, calculator, division

I am creating a calculator program in python. It must get maximum 5 numbers from the user and then the user enters the calculation sign they want to use. Everything is working, the `+` the `-` and the `*`, but the division `/` does not work and it returns the following error:

```
CALCULATOR
ENTER NUMBER 1. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION4
ENTER NUMBER 2. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION7
ENTER NUMBER 3. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION
ENTER THE CALCULATION + - / */
THE RESULT IS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\calc.py", line 52, in <module>
    print  "THE RESULT IS", int(NUMBER1) / int(NUMBER2) / int(NUMBER3) / int(NUMBER4) / int(NUMBER5)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

The calculator program:

```
from goto import goto, label
print(   "CALCULATOR"    )
NUMBER1 = 0; NUMBER2 = 0; NUMBER3 = 0; NUMBER4 = 0; NUMBER5 = 0;

NUMBER1 = raw_input(   "ENTER NUMBER 1. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION"    )
if NUMBER1 == " ":
  goto .end;

NUMBER2 = raw_input(   "ENTER NUMBER 2. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION"   )
if NUMBER2 == " ":
  NUMBER2 = 0;
  goto .calculation;

NUMBER3 = raw_input(   "ENTER NUMBER 3. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION"   )

if NUMBER3 == " ":
  NUMBER3 = 0;
  goto .calculation;

NUMBER4 = raw_input(   "ENTER NUMBER 4. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION"   )
if NUMBER4 == " ":
  NUMBER4 = 0;
  goto .calculation;

NUMBER5 = raw_input(   "ENTER NUMBER 5. TYPE SPACE TO ENTER CALCULATION"   )
if NUMBER5 == " ":
  NUMBER5 = 0;
  goto .calculation;

label .calculation

CALCULATION = raw_input(    "ENTER THE CALCULATION + - / *")


if CALCULATION == "+":
  print  "THE RESULT IS", int(NUMBER1) + int(NUMBER2) + int(NUMBER3) + int(NUMBER4) + int(NUMBER5)

if CALCULATION == "-":
  print  "THE RESULT IS", int(NUMBER1) - int(NUMBER2) - int(NUMBER3) - int(NUMBER4) - int(NUMBER5)

if CALCULATION == "*":
  print  "THE RESULT IS", int(NUMBER1) * int(NUMBER2) * int(NUMBER3) * int(NUMBER4) * int(NUMBER5)

if CALCULATION == "/":
  print  "THE RESULT IS", int(NUMBER1) / int(NUMBER2) / int(NUMBER3) / int(NUMBER4) / int(NUMBER5)


label .end

print "";print  "------------------------------------";print "";
print   "PROGRAM END."
print  "THANK YOU FOR USING THE CALCULATOR."
print  "SEE YOU NEXT TIME."
print  "BYE!"
```

Why does the error occur only when dividing the numbers and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't divide a number by 0, the error is clear.

Your code is not complete, we can't help us more. Try to give us a short but complete example.

Comment: Hi. thank you. tha whole code is in the question. what example are you talking about? How can i fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the first answer, that you can't divide by 0 ever, the error is implying that. But on another note, you can consider implementing the floor division which works for int and non-int numbers. Although that's your personal preference and depends on what the program requires.

floor division is

```
 //
```

Comment: Hi thanks. What is the floor division? I just see //

Comment: @Zekros Admines: floor division operator is //

Comment: but still trying to understand why you have NUMBER2  and on wards set to 0? and I believe you don't need the ";" after each variable, that's mainly for the other OOP languages like C++, C, Java, C#....